All Slip ring motors showing High rotor current in our electrical system
All slip ring motors on our plant showing high rotor current. Stator current is high too but not above the limit but rotor current is off the charts up to 600 amp. Motors work just fine on no load. all slip ring motors are showing same  behavior. electrical system works on 50 Hz frequency and 420 Vac. there is no voltage drop or unbalance voltage nor unbalance current.
Does anybody have an idea what is going on?

it's either normal, or you may be measuring incorrectly

It would be useful to know more about the motors, in particular the power ratings, but ideally a photo of the nameplate.  Also, how exactly are you measuring the currents?
